# call php code in delphi

Tags: php, mysql, delphi

i want to use a MySQL database in Delphi but my host server close the remote connection so i should write a php code and put it in host for read\write data and call those code from Delphi 
i do some googling and all of the example of php code for connect and r/w data use echo command to show the result in browser but i want to pass those result to Delphi so my first question is how can i save the result into some variable for send to Delphi and in Delphi how can i call that code from the host and catch the result 
for example i found this php code:

config.php :

```
<?php
$config=array(
'host'=>'test.com',
'user'=>'usertest',
'password'=>'passtest',
'database'=>'testdb'
);
```

db.php :

```
<?php
require_once 'config.php';
MySQL_connect($config['host'],$config['user'],$config['password']) or
die("error in connection");  ////my first question is here**
MySQL_select_db($config['database']);
MySQL_set_charset("utf8");
?>
```

read function php file :

```
<?php
include 'db.php';
$query1=  mysql_query("SELECT  * from test");
$query=  mysql_fetch_assoc($query1)
echo $query['id'];      ///and second question is here and next 2 line 
echo $query['name'];
echo $query['family'];
?>
```

*** as you see when the connection to the bank was failed and when the query was run successfully the result print in browser with echo command but i want to save this result and pass them to the Delphi
so first please tell me how can i save this result in some variable and second please tell how can i call this procedure from Delphi and catch the result

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It's awful and has been removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) helps explain best practices. Make **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will end up with severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: Presumably the php code is running on the server. No variables or files will help you because they will be on the server and your delphi code runs on the client. What you need to do is make a web service and access that from your delphi client. Now, your service provider has done you a favour because direct db connection over Internet is an epic security risk.

Comment: thank's to all but the security is not important to me for this project now i want just some php code to connect and r\w data either with pdo or anything else to put them in server and some delphi code to call those php procedure from client and catch the result. can anyone help me for this 2 code?

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/ http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/  You know what you need to do, now you need to make an effort to code it up

Comment: ya that's right but that "make an effort" need brave hart and say it is very easier than do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the same problem that you have generating a WebServive in PHP that connects to the Database. Later in Delphi you can connect to the webservice and get the data without problems.

**(STEP1)** To create the WebService (if you don't have php experience) you can use the library [nuSOAP](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nusoap/). [Here you can find](http://neftali.clubdelphi.com/15-aplicacion-de-acceso-a-datos-introduccion/) the differents steps to do a simple webservice to connect to a MySQL database and run querys. With this the WS returns the query using JSON.

You can see a sample working of WS with nuSOAP here:

- [WSDL generated](http://neftali.clubdelphi.com/agenda/listado2.php?wsdl)
- [The estructure of created process](http://neftali.clubdelphi.com/agenda/listado2.php).

Some samples of data result for (to test in Delphi):

- [The user with ID=10](http://neftali.clubdelphi.com/agenda/listado.php?user=10)
- [The first 20 users](http://neftali.clubdelphi.com/agenda/listado.php?num=20)
- [All the users](http://neftali.clubdelphi.com/agenda/listado.php?num=-1) (param = -1)

**(STEP2)** To connect with delphi application, you can use Indy (for old delphi versions) or REST components (`TRESTRequest`, `TRESTClient`, `TRESTResponse`) in new delhi versions. [Here you can find](http://neftali.clubdelphi.com/35-generacion-de-un-cliente-webservice-en-delphi/) differents options and codes to connect. Another alternative is use SOAP (THTTPRIO) and WSDL importer.

You can download PHP files and delphi code if you want to test it.
The page is in spanish but you can use Google translate and see the code to understand it.

Answer (score 1):

The easy way it's to make request exectly to php script using idhttp1 and show response with JSON, but it's not safety

```
http://test.com/?r=SELECT_*_FROM_TABLENAME
$r=mysql_query($_GET['r']);
```

or

```
http://test.com/?action=SELECT&table=TABLENAME
$r=mysql_query($_GET['action']+' FROM '+$_GET['table']);
```

or use indy REST